# Change view with swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I change the view with swiftUI? This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Click")
           .onTapGesture {
               print("clicked")
               NextView()
                    
                
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    var body: some View {
      
            Text("Next View")
                
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView()
    }
}
```

How can I view the "nextview" when clicking the text on the first view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
                Text("Click")
                .onTapGesture {
                   print("clicked")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    var body: some View {
  
            Text("Next View")
            
    
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView()
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, adding `.onTapGesture` just disables the `NavigationLink` altogether.